# Whats wrong with the following Spring PointCut?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have a point cut which is used to advise the method which is declared inside an interface called Repository. But in run time the aspect is not applied. Whats wrong with my pointcut?

Here is the pointcut:-

```
@Around("execution (* *..Repository+.save*(..))" + " && args(entity,..) && target(target)")
    public Object cacheEvictOnSaveSingle(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Region entity,
            RegionRepositoryCassandraImpl target) {
}
```

And the Repository Interface is like :-

```
public interface Repository<ENTITY extends Entity<IDENTITY>, IDENTITY extends Serializable, DATAOBJECT> {

    /**
     * Find.
     *
     * @param id the id
     * @return the t
     */
    public ENTITY find(IDENTITY id);

    /**
     * Save.
     *
     * @param entity the entity
     */
    public void save(ENTITY entity);

    /**
     * Save async.
     *
     * @param entity the entity
     * @return the result set future
     */
    public ResultSetFuture saveAsync(ENTITY entity);

    /**
     * Save.
     *
     * @param entity the entity
     * @param batchStatement the batch statement
     */
    public void save(ENTITY entity, BatchStatement batchStatement);

    /**
     * Save.
     *
     * @param entities the entities
     */
    public void save(List<ENTITY> entities);

    /**
     * Save async.
     *
     * @param entities the entities
     * @return the result set future
     */
    public ResultSetFuture saveAsync(List<ENTITY> entities);

    /**
     * Save.
     *
     * @param entities the entities
     * @param batchStatement the batch statement
     */
    public void save(List<ENTITY> entities, BatchStatement batchStatement);

    /**
     * Delete.
     *
     * @param id the id
     */
    public void delete(IDENTITY id);

    /**
     * Delete async.
     *
     * @param id the id
     * @return the result set future
     */
    public ResultSetFuture deleteAsync(IDENTITY id);

    /**
     * Delete.
     *
     * @param id the id
     * @param batchStatement the batch statement
     */
    public void delete(IDENTITY id, BatchStatement batchStatement);

    /**
     * Delete.
     *
     * @param ids the ids
     */
    public void delete(List<IDENTITY> ids);

    /**
     * Delete async.
     *
     * @param ids the ids
     * @return the result set future
     */
    public ResultSetFuture deleteAsync(List<IDENTITY> ids);

    /**
     * Delete.
     *
     * @param ids the ids
     * @param batchStatement the batch statement
     */
    public void delete(List<IDENTITY> ids, BatchStatement batchStatement);

}
```

This is implemented inside an abstract class as:-

```
@Override
    public void save(ENTITY entity) {
        BatchStatement batchStatement = new BatchStatement();
        addEntityToSaveBatch(batchStatement, entity);

        session.execute(batchStatement);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.dbclient.repository.Repository#saveAsync(com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.dbclient.dto.compute.Entity)
     */
    @Override
    public ResultSetFuture saveAsync(ENTITY entity) {
        BatchStatement batchStatement = new BatchStatement();
        addEntityToSaveBatch(batchStatement, entity);

        return session.executeAsync(batchStatement);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.dbclient.repository.Repository#save(com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.dbclient.dto.compute.Entity, com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement)
     */
    @Override
    public void save(ENTITY entity, BatchStatement batchStatement) {
        addEntityToSaveBatch(batchStatement, entity);
    }
```

Can you help me solving this?

Comment: My class Extends the above mentioned Abstract Class:- public class RegionRepositoryCassandraImpl extends EntityRepository<Region, UUID, RegionDO>
  implements RegionRepository {

Comment: Are you using CGLIB or JDK based proxies in Spring AOP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in method signature, it should be :-

```java
@Around("execution (* *..Repository+.save*(..))" + " && args(entity,..) && target(target)")
public Object cacheEvictOnSaveSingle(
    ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint,
    Entity<UUID> entity,
    RegionRepositoryCassandraImpl target
) {
    // ...
}
```